# C# Converting JSON to Javascript object notation

Tags: javascript, c#, json, node.js

In C# I wish to convert JSON to JS object notation so for example this:

```
{  
   "personalizations":[  
      {  
         "to":[  
            {  
               "email":"test@gmail.com",
               "name":"John"
            }
         ],
         "subject":"Hello, World!"
      }
   ]
}
```

Will produce something like this:

```
personalizations[0].to[0].email="test@gmail.com";
personalizations[0].subject="John";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: JSON.parse ????

Comment: JSON === JavaScript Object Notation ... there is no conversion

Comment: Sorry this is a C# question.. can't seem to be able to edit the question. So in c# I wish to generate these property assignments from this JSON.

Comment: Are you trying to get the JSON as a object to manipulate, or refactoring the JSON to code?

Comment: There used to be a library called NewtonSoft which used to do this. You can look into it

Answer (score 1):

You could get the single pathes to the values and build a string upon.

You may need some better regular expression for checking keys for using dot notation.

```js
function getParts(object, path) {
    path = path || [];
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(function (r, k) {
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            return r.concat(getParts(object[k], path.concat(k)));
        }
        r.push(path.concat(k, object[k]));
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var data = { personalizations: [{ to: [{ email: "test@gmail.com", name: "John" }], subject: "Hello, World!" }] },
    result = getParts(data).map(function (a) {
        var value = a.pop();
        return a.map(function (k, i) {
            return /^[a-z_$][a-z0-9_$]*$/.test(k) ? (i ? '.' : '') + k : '[' + k + ']';
        }).concat('=' + (typeof value === 'string' ? '"' + value + '"' : value) + ';').join('');
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the native js function: JSON.parse(your_json) ?

Comment: I know you do not have enough rep to comment, but I'd request you to keep patience. Putting comment as answer can attract downvotes. So if you choose to answer, please make sure it justifies the term Answer

Comment: @Rajesh A useful link: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Do you suggest that I delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. That's what the word means.

I assume what you mean is you want to convert a JSON declaration into assignment statements, and you can do this easily enough:

```js
var data = {  
   "personalizations":[  
      {  
         "to":[  
            {  
               "email":"test@gmail.com",
               "name":"John"
            }
         ],
         "subject":"Hello, World!"
      }
   ]
};

var personalizations = [];

for(var i = 0; i< data.personalizations.length; i++) {
   var p = {};
   p.subject = data.personalizations[i].subject;
   // etc
   
   personalizations[i] = p;
}

console.log(personalizations);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  var oldObject = {  
   "personalizations":[  
      {  
         "to":[  
            {  
               "email":"test@gmail.com",
               "name":"John"
            }
         ],
         "subject":"Hello, World!"
      }
   ]
};

var newObject = JSON.parse(oldObject);
```

Comment: You've passed an already-js-object to JSON.parse, not a JSON string

Comment: Sorry guys this is a C# question.

Comment: Oh, sorry thought it was javaScript.